# mongo: getting lots of connections when no backend is talking to db

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I just created a mongo replicated setup with two instances. The logs show a lot of connections starting and ending every second. The logs are below. Any idea why there are so many connections when I don't have any servers talking to the DB? I'm also confused why the port the connections are coming from keep increasing.

Primary Mongo Instance

```
$ tail  /log/mongod.log
2015-02-08T21:46:40.679+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from <local machine private IP from EC2>:43833 #58 (6 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:46:40.680+0000 [conn58]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
2015-02-08T21:47:05.416+0000 [conn10] end connection <local machine private IP from EC2>:43719 (5 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:05.416+0000 [conn13] end connection <local machine private IP from EC2>:43724 (4 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:10.699+0000 [conn58] end connection <local machine private IP from EC2>:43833 (3 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:10.700+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from <local machine private IP from EC2>:43835 #59 (4 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:10.702+0000 [conn59]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
2015-02-08T21:47:40.720+0000 [conn59] end connection <local machine private IP from EC2>:43835 (3 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:40.723+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from <local machine private IP from EC2>:43836 #60 (4 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:40.724+0000 [conn60]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
```

Secondary Mongo Instance

```
$ tail /log/mongod.log 
2015-02-08T21:46:39.732+0000 [conn285]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
2015-02-08T21:46:59.877+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from <local machine elastic IP from EC2>:42568 #286 (4 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:46:59.881+0000 [conn286] end connection <local machine elastic IP from EC2>:42568 (3 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:05.424+0000 [conn191] end connection <local machine private IP from EC2>:44756 (2 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:09.750+0000 [conn285] end connection <local machine private IP from EC2>:43873 (1 connection now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:09.752+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from <local machine private IP from EC2>:43874 #287 (2 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:09.753+0000 [conn287]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
2015-02-08T21:47:39.772+0000 [conn287] end connection <local machine private IP from EC2>:43874 (1 connection now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:39.774+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from <local machine private IP from EC2>:43875 #288 (2 connections now open)
2015-02-08T21:47:39.775+0000 [conn288]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
```

I am also a bit confused why the elastic IP is being used in some cases (see secondary log). I assume using the public IP would cause me to get charged by AWS?

Comment: only 2 members in the replica set? that's not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connections that are coming every 30 seconds are the heartbeat threads, coming from the other replica set member to make sure this member is still alive and healthy. They use whatever IP is in your replica set configuration.

The connection using the public IP seems to end its connection very quickly. Turn up your log level and figure out what it's doing?

Comment: Is there anyway to reduce the log spam? I guess its only two logs per minute though.